What is the law regarding impersonating a police officer?
There is a video of someone heckling Kamala Harris on the Jimmy Kimmel talk show.  The end of the video shows an interaction between a security guard and the heckler, in which during an attempted arrest the security guard claims to be a police officer, but later saying that they are "working security here" and refuses requests for identification.
For the purposes of this question, assume the person claiming to be a police officer is not actually a police officer out of uniform who is refusing to show their identification.
If this was the UK I believe this would be impersonating a police officer, possibly under the Police Act 1996:

Any person who with intent to deceive impersonates a member of a police force or special constable, or makes any statement or does any act calculated falsely to suggest that he is such a member or constable, shall be guilty of an offence and liable on summary conviction to imprisonment for a term not exceeding six months or to a fine not exceeding level 5 on the standard scale, or to both.

What is the legal situation in the US?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This is a matter of state law upon which there may be material differences between U.S. states. "Jimmy Kimmel Live!, sometimes shortened to JKL, is an American late-night political satire talk show, created and hosted by Jimmy Kimmel, and broadcast on ABC. The nightly hour-long show is held at Hollywood Masonic Temple in Hollywood, California." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Kimmel_Live! So, presumably, California law would be the law relevant to this question.

@ohwilleke Thanks, added.

It's possible a policeman does also work security at a location.

This is a matter of state law upon which there may be material differences between U.S. states.

Jimmy Kimmel Live!, sometimes shortened to JKL, is an American
late-night political satire talk show, created and hosted by Jimmy
Kimmel, and broadcast on ABC. The nightly hour-long show is held at
Hollywood Masonic Temple in Hollywood, California.

(Source)
Therefore, California law is the law relevant to this question. In California, where the incident took place, the relevant statute is California Penal Code § 538d.
The California criminal statute related to impersonating an officer only imposes criminal sanctions for using a uniform, badge, or other tangible item that would ordinarily be reserved for police officers in California, or making a digital representation to this effect. Its terms do not include an in person oral representation that someone is a police officer. This is a significantly narrower statute than the corresponding statute in the U.K.
The facts in the question are that someone who was not a police officer orally represented in an in person interaction that they were a police officer when they were not. But there is no allegation that a false badge or police uniform was used. So, this statute was not violated in the incident in this clip.
The California statute states that:

(a) Any person other than one who by law is given the authority of a
peace officer, who willfully wears, exhibits, or uses the authorized
uniform, insignia, emblem, device, label, certificate, card, or
writing, of a peace officer, with the intent of fraudulently
impersonating a peace officer, or of fraudulently inducing the belief
that they are a peace officer, or who willfully and credibly
impersonates a peace officer through or on an internet website, or by
other electronic means, for purposes of defrauding another, is guilty
of a misdemeanor.
(b) (1) Any person, other than the one who by law is given the
authority of a peace officer, who willfully wears, exhibits, or uses
the badge of a peace officer with the intent of fraudulently
impersonating a peace officer, or of fraudulently inducing the belief
that they are a peace officer, is guilty of a misdemeanor punishable
by imprisonment in a county jail not to exceed one year, by a fine not
to exceed two thousand dollars ($2,000), or by both that imprisonment
and fine.
(2) Any person who willfully wears or uses any badge that falsely
purports to be authorized for the use of one who by law is given the
authority of a peace officer, or which so resembles the authorized
badge of a peace officer as would deceive any ordinary reasonable
person into believing that it is authorized for the use of one who by
law is given the authority of a peace officer, for the purpose of
fraudulently impersonating a peace officer, or of fraudulently
inducing the belief that they are a peace officer, is guilty of a
misdemeanor punishable by imprisonment in a county jail not to exceed
one year, by a fine not to exceed two thousand dollars ($2,000), or by
both that imprisonment and fine.
(c) (1) Except as provided in subdivision (d), any person who
willfully wears, exhibits, or uses, or who willfully makes, sells,
loans, gives, or transfers to another, any badge, insignia, emblem,
device, or any label, certificate, card, or writing, which falsely
purports to be authorized for the use of one who by law is given the
authority of a peace officer, or which so resembles the authorized
badge, insignia, emblem, device, label, certificate, card, or writing
of a peace officer as would deceive an ordinary reasonable person into
believing that it is authorized for the use of one who by law is given
the authority of a peace officer, is guilty of a misdemeanor
punishable by imprisonment in a county jail not to exceed six months,
by a fine not to exceed two thousand dollars ($2,000), or by both that
imprisonment and fine, except that any person who makes or sells any
badge under the circumstances described in this subdivision is subject
to a fine not to exceed fifteen thousand dollars ($15,000).
(2) A local law enforcement agency in the jurisdiction that files
charges against a person for a violation of paragraph (1) shall seize
the badge, insignia, emblem, device, label, certificate, card, or
writing described in paragraph (1).
(d) (1) The head of an agency that employs peace officers, as defined
in Sections 830.1 and 830.2, is authorized to issue identification in
the form of a badge, insignia, emblem, device, label, certificate,
card, or writing that clearly states that the person has honorably
retired following service as a peace officer from that agency. The
identification authorized pursuant to this subdivision is separate and
distinct from the identification authorized by Article 2 (commencing
with Section 25450) of Chapter 2 of Division 5 of Title 4 of Part 6.
(2) If the head of an agency issues a badge to an honorably retired
peace officer that is not affixed to a plaque or other memento
commemorating the retiree’s service for the agency, the words
“Honorably Retired” shall be clearly visible above, underneath, or on
the badge itself.
(3) The head of an agency that employs peace officers as defined in
Sections 830.1 and 830.2 is authorized to revoke identification
granted pursuant to this subdivision in the event of misuse or abuse.
(4) For the purposes of this subdivision, the term “honorably retired”
does not include an officer who has agreed to a service retirement in
lieu of termination.
(e) (1) Vendors of law enforcement uniforms shall verify that a person
purchasing a uniform identifying a law enforcement agency is an
employee of the agency identified on the uniform. Presentation and
examination of a valid identification card with a picture of the
person purchasing the uniform and identification, on the letterhead of
the law enforcement agency, of the person buying the uniform as an
employee of the agency identified on the uniform shall be sufficient
verification.
(2) Any uniform vendor who sells a uniform identifying a law
enforcement agency, without verifying that the purchaser is an
employee of the agency, is guilty of a misdemeanor, punishable by a
fine of not more than one thousand dollars ($1,000).
(3) This subdivision shall not apply if the uniform is to be used
solely as a prop for a motion picture, television, video production,
or a theatrical event, and prior written permission has been obtained
from the identified law enforcement agency.
(Amended by Stats. 2022, Ch. 954, Sec. 1. (AB 1899) Effective January
1, 2023.)

